# Gradle NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: gradle, geb

So I am trying build a simple gradle app and when I run it, I getting

```
geb.ConfigurationLoader$UnableToLoadException: Unable to load configuration @ 'file:/Users/john/Development/groovy/gradlegebautomation/build/resources/test/GebConfig.groovy' (with environment: null)
    at geb.ConfigurationLoader.loadRawConfig(ConfigurationLoader.groovy:297)
    at geb.ConfigurationLoader.loadRawConfig(ConfigurationLoader.groovy:281)
    at geb.ConfigurationLoader.getConf(ConfigurationLoader.groovy:161)
    at geb.ConfigurationLoader.doGetConf(ConfigurationLoader.groovy:139)
    at geb.ConfigurationLoader.getConf(ConfigurationLoader.groovy:95)
    at geb.ConfigurationLoader.getConf(ConfigurationLoader.groovy:114)
    at geb.spock.GebSpec.createConf(GebSpec.groovy:29)
    at geb.spock.GebSpec.createBrowser(GebSpec.groovy:33)
    at geb.spock.GebSpec.getBrowser(GebSpec.groovy:38)
    at geb.spock.GebSpec.methodMissing(GebSpec.groovy:51)
    at geb.spock.GebReportingSpec.setupSpec(GebReportingSpec.groovy:30)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/ivy/core/report/ResolveReport
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2436)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1793)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.util.LazyReference.getLocked(LazyReference.java:46)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.util.LazyReference.get(LazyReference.java:33)
    at groovy.grape.GrapeIvy.<init>(GrapeIvy.groovy:75)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:310)
    at groovy.grape.Grape.getInstance(Grape.java:101)
    at groovy.grape.Grape.grab(Grape.java:136)
    at groovy.grape.GrabAnnotationTransformation.visit(GrabAnnotationTransformation.java:291)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.transform.ASTTransformationVisitor$3.call(ASTTransformationVisitor.java:319)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:903)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:542)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:519)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:279)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:258)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:244)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:202)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:212)
    at groovy.util.ConfigSlurper.parse(ConfigSlurper.groovy:146)
    at geb.ConfigurationLoader.loadRawConfig(ConfigurationLoader.groovy:295)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ivy.core.report.ResolveReport
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    ... 32 more
```

So I created the folder structure src/test/groovy and src/main/groovy. I also created inside of test/groovy, another folder called store. So I can get this to work if I put the GebConfig.groovy in the src/test/groovy and src/test/groovy/store. Anything else I get the error above. Here is my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'groovy'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    groovy group: 'org.codehaus.groovy', name: 'groovy', version: '2.0.5'
    groovy group: 'org.apache.ivy', name:'ivy', version:'2.2.0'
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.0.5'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
    testCompile 'org.spockframework:spock-core:0.7-groovy-2.0'
    testCompile 'org.gebish:geb-spock:0.9.0-RC-1'
    testCompile 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-firefox-driver:2.31.0'
}
```

Here is my test

```
package groovy.store

import geb.spock.GebReportingSpec

class SimpleSpec extends GebReportingSpec {

    def "Doing a simple Guest checkout"() {
        given: "A test"
            def hello

        when: ""
            hello = "Hello"

        then:
            assert hello == "Hello"
    }
}
```

Thoughts?

UPDATE v1:

Ok, it looks like I needed to add a new dependency in my build.gradle. I added the ivy dep and now I am getting this error:

```
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':compileTestGroovy'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:72)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.CacheLockHandlingTaskExecuter$1.run(CacheLockHandlingTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:179)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:232)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.longRunningOperation(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:142)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.java:83)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.CacheLockHandlingTaskExecuter.execute(CacheLockHandlingTaskExecuter.java:32)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:41)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:42)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:275)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.executeTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:52)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:38)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:30)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:84)
    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:29)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:67)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.TaskCacheLockHandlingBuildExecuter$1.run(TaskCacheLockHandlingBuildExecuter.java:31)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:124)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:112)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.useCache(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:134)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.java:79)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.TaskCacheLockHandlingBuildExecuter.execute(TaskCacheLockHandlingBuildExecuter.java:29)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:67)
    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:166)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:113)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:81)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessGradleLauncherActionExecuter.execute(InProcessGradleLauncherActionExecuter.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessGradleLauncherActionExecuter.execute(InProcessGradleLauncherActionExecuter.java:25)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:50)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:171)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:201)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:174)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:170)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:139)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:48)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:26)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.ApiGroovyCompiler.execute(ApiGroovyCompiler.java:121)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.ApiGroovyCompiler.execute(ApiGroovyCompiler.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.daemon.CompilerDaemonServer.execute(CompilerDaemonServer.java:52)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:355)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:66)
```

Here is my GebConfig

```
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver

//reportsDir = "target/geb-reports"

// default is to use firefox
driver = {
    def driver = new FirefoxDriver()
    driver.manage().window().maximize()
    return driver
}

environments {
    'firefox' {
        driver = {
            def driver = new FirefoxDriver()
            driver.manage().window().maximize()
            return driver
        }   
    }
}
```

UPDATE V2:

Oh, I see if I go a little higher in the stack I see the following:

```
startup failed:
Could not instantiate global transform class org.spockframework.compiler.SpockTransform specified at jar:file:/Users/john/.gradle/caches/artifacts-23/filestore/org.spockframework/spock-core/0.7-groovy-2.0/jar/4de0b428de0c14b6eb6375d8174f71848cbfc1d7/spock-core-0.7-groovy-2.0.jar!/META-INF/services/org.codehaus.groovy.transform.ASTTransformation  because of exception org.spockframework.util.IncompatibleGroovyVersionException: The Spock compiler plugin cannot execute because Spock 0.7.0-groovy-2.0 is not compatible with Groovy 1.8.6. For more information, see http://versioninfo.spockframework.org
Spock location: file:/Users/john/.gradle/caches/artifacts-23/filestore/org.spockframework/spock-core/0.7-groovy-2.0/jar/4de0b428de0c14b6eb6375d8174f71848cbfc1d7/spock-core-0.7-groovy-2.0.jar
Groovy location: file:/Users/john/bin/gradle-1.5/lib/groovy-all-1.8.6.jar
```

UPDATE v3:

So I added regular groovy into my dependencies, see above. I am not passing the compile stage and failing at the test stage. Here is the message that is coming up in the report

```
geb.ConfigurationLoader$UnableToLoadException: Unable to load configuration from class 'class GebConfig' (with environment: null)
    at geb.ConfigurationLoader.loadRawConfig(ConfigurationLoader.groovy:297)
    at geb.ConfigurationLoader.loadRawConfig(ConfigurationLoader.groovy:290)
    at geb.ConfigurationLoader.getConf(ConfigurationLoader.groovy:226)
    at geb.ConfigurationLoader.doGetConfFromClass(ConfigurationLoader.groovy:200)
    at geb.ConfigurationLoader.getConf(ConfigurationLoader.groovy:95)
    at geb.ConfigurationLoader.getConf(ConfigurationLoader.groovy:114)
    at geb.spock.GebSpec.createConf(GebSpec.groovy:29)
    at geb.spock.GebSpec.createBrowser(GebSpec.groovy:33)
    at geb.spock.GebSpec.getBrowser(GebSpec.groovy:38)
    at geb.spock.GebSpec.methodMissing(GebSpec.groovy:51)
    at geb.spock.GebReportingSpec.setupSpec(GebReportingSpec.groovy:30)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:249)
    at groovy.util.ConfigSlurper.parse(ConfigSlurper.groovy:127)
    at geb.ConfigurationLoader.loadRawConfig(ConfigurationLoader.groovy:295)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: No suitable ClassLoader found for grab
    at groovy.grape.GrapeIvy.chooseClassLoader(GrapeIvy.groovy:181)
    at groovy.grape.GrapeIvy.grab(GrapeIvy.groovy:247)
    at groovy.grape.GrapeIvy.grab(GrapeIvy.groovy:236)
    at groovy.grape.Grape.grab(Grape.java:129)
    ... 13 more
```

Comment: Do you use `@Grab` anywhere, for example in your `GebConfig.groovy`?

Comment: hm...
you reed your output?
`geb.ConfigurationLoader$UnableToLoadException: Unable to load configuration @ 'file:/Users/john/Development/groovy/gradlegebautomation/build/resources/test/GebConfig.groovy' (with environment: null)`
in your GebConfig.groovy suck configuration.
Try run geb+spock example.

Comment: I had @Grab in my gebconfig and added support for ivy. Now getting new error, see update above

Comment: Which task is failing? What's the compiler's error message?

Comment: Ok this is all fixed up now. Appears when I was trying to figure this out I created two GebConfigs. Removed the one that should not have been used and now everything is working as designed. Thanks

Comment: You can use either the Gradle "eclipse" or "idea" plugin to auto-generate IDE project files that setup your classpath for your project.  It looks to me like your just missing the project configuration.  Unfortunately, you don't say whether or not your even using an IDE and so I cannot say for sure.

Comment: Consider posting your solution as the Answer rather than a comment. Questions listed with no accepted answers make helpful folk think you're still stuck!

Answer (score 0):

what bothered me first on this one was that there was no choice of which environment to be used from the config file; your first list said:
 favorite

So I am trying build a simple gradle app and when I run it, I getting

**Unable to load configuration @ 'file:/Users/john/Development/groovy/gradlegebautomation/build/resources/test/GebConfig.groovy' (with environment: null)**

so i'm probably off on this but i'd try to give it a choice as to which environment to use, say .environment('firefox') - sorry forgot the syntax